Empty Scratch Org
When I create a scratch org it is empty. Nothing from the source org is there.
In my production instance (also my source org) I have done the following:

Verified I have Create Org Shape permissions
Enabled org shapes and put my orgs 15 digit Id in the settings

I have run these commands:

sf auth web login --alias prod
sf org create shape --target-org prod
sf org shape list


Then I run commands to create the scratch org:

sf org create scratch --definition-file config/project-scratch-def.json --alias shapeOrg --set-default --target-dev-hub prod

Here are the contents of my scratch-def file:
{
  "orgName": "anOrgName",
  "sourceOrg":"15 dig orgId"
}

When I open the scratch created from the command above it doesn't have any code or config from the source org. Any help is appreciated.

Scratch orgs are not like sandboxes from a production org in that they do not have the same shape or content. They don't even have to have the same namespace.
The org shape mechanism can be used to ensure features etc. can be set in the scratch org.
Alternatively, you can use a scratch org snapshot to have the scratch org pre-populated, based on a previously initialized scratch org. Note, however, that you have to recreate the snapshots every (currently) 90 days since they expire like ordinary scratch orgs (just a bit slower).
The dev hub you use simply dictates the namespaces available, controls the limits on active and daily creations of scratch orgs and stores the details of created packages and package versions.
To be clear; scratch orgs are always empty unless created from a snapshot that has content.
You will need to recreate your prod environment using an org shape then populate it with metadata by ensuring you have all the required metadata in version control (e.g. a git repo) that you can push to the new scratch org. You can use the CLI to pull or retrieve all the metadata from your prod org, for storage in version control, and use the CLI to push or deploy this metadata to a scratch org that you can use directly, or that you use to create a snapshot.
Org-centric development was the original approach Salesforce used, which was a really bad idea since the "source of truth" was an org that could not show you how it used to look (there was no version control). You had to use specially related sandboxes, with clones of the metadata, to permit changes to be developed in isolation, for promotion to the prod org via change sets. This was wholly unsatisfactory and did not align with software development best practice.
Scratch orgs and the version control "source of truth" were part of Salesforce's SFDX (Developer Experience) process, intended to align better with software development best practice.

Thanks for this tip, I've followed all the documentation and keep running into a problem...these commands want to create a snap shot of scratch org, not my devHub (which is prod for me). If i try to use my devHub/prod in the command I get an error that the org is not an active scratch. A snapshot of all my empty scratch orgs isn't helpful. Do you know how I can create a snapshot of prod/devhub instance?

You cannot. See the update. You need to pull the metadata off "prod" to store it in version control (e.g. guthub, bitbucket, gitlab or similar) for subsequent deployment to scratch orgs (or to prod, once ready).

Thanks for all this info! I'll just deploy my repo to my scratch org! Thanks a bunch.
